# LazyInitializationException : Why can't Hibernate create a session on lazy loading?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, lazy-loading

My project use to have a lot of @Transactional method everywhere. Now because of business logic I do not want to rollback when I have an issue, but want to set my object to an error status (aka saved in the db, so definitly not rollback), so I removed a few @Transactional to start.

Now the issue is where there is a lazy loading there is no session, thus spawning a LazyInitializationException.

Now here are my following trouble-shooting and solution seeking so far :

- We're using annotation configuration, so no xml configuration here.
- For each action using the database, an EntityManager (defined as an attribute and @Autowired in the service) is created and then deleted (I can clearly see it in the logs when adding the configuration to see them), which apparently is normal according to the Spring documentation.
- Using @PersistenceContext or @PersistenceUnit, either with a EntityManagerFactory or with EntityManager doesn't work.
- I *can* load the lazy-loaded attribute I want to use with Hibernate.initialize(), and it then doesn't spawn a LazyInitializationException.

Now my question is : Why can't hibernate do it by itself ? It's seems trivial to me that if I'm using a lazy loading, I want Hibernate to create a session (which he seems perfectly able to do when doing Hibernate.initialize()) to load the date automatically.

Would there be a way to spawn a new entity manager to be use inside my method so Hibernate doesn't create and recreate one all the time ? I really feel like I'm missing something basic about Hibernate, lazy loading and sessions that makes this whole mess a lot less complicated.

Here is an example :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tata")
public class Tata {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "tata_id")
    private Long id;

    // getter / setter etc
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "toto")
public class Toto {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "toto_id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tata_id")
    private Tata tata;

    // getter / setter etc
}

@Service("totoManager")
public class TotoManager extends GenericManagerImpl {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private TotoRepository totoRepository;

    public void doSomethingWithTotos() throws XDExceptionImpl {

        List<Toto> totos = this.totoRepository.findAll();

        for (toto toto : totos) {
        // LazyInitializationException here
            LOGGER.info("tata : " + toto.getTata().getId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when do you want hibernate to initialize a session?

Comment: When I want to reach the tata in toto, because per definition it's not loaded and it need to get to the db to load it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate can do it by itself. With setting property `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true` (for spring boot it should be `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`) you can load any lazy property when transaction is closed. This approach has huge drawback: each time you load lazy property, hibernate opens session and creates transaction in background.

I would recommed fetch lazy properties by [entityGraphs](https://www.jeejava.com/spring-data-jpa-entity-graphs/). So you doesnt have to move persistent context do upper level or change fetch type in your entities.

Comment: That's working, thanks. I'm going to look at entityGraphs, but that being said from what I saw from logging transactions and sessions, he is creating a fuck ton of session and entitymanager all the time. Isn't there a way to just have him maintain a session for at least a short amount of time for performance sake ? At this point I'm going to take the performance hit over having transaction defined everywhere in the code to avoid that issue ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to read something about **Open session in view** to understand why *Lazy loading* does not work out of session/transaction. If you want you can set property `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true` and it will load your lazy loaded data.

Comment: I'm still having LazyInitializationException while using spring.jpa.open-in-view=true

Comment: can you post sample application somewhere?

Comment: Can't really do since I'm not suppose to put company code here, and also because it's a pretty big chunk of code. I will try and make a sample of how it is.

Comment: Updated my post with an example